# Auto-save attachments in Outlook 2010

Tags: vb.net, outlook

My goal is to be able to save attachments from a specific email address to a folder locally. I have created a VB script but for some reason it doesn't work.

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk (itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
Dim dateFormat
dateFormat = Format(Now, "dd-mm-yyyy H-mm")
saveFolder = "c:\temp\"
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments        
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & dateFormate & objAtt.DisplayName        
        Set objAtt = Nothing    
    Next
End Sub
```

I've tried to created a new module and a new rule so it will run the script when the message arrives from the specific address. I have also tried to put the script in "ThisOutlookSession" but nothing works.

Comment: Are you sure it's running at all? Maybe the code isn't being triggered under the conditions you want.

Comment: i have no clue. How do i check that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to run the script manually under the debugger?

Try to choose another drive. The C: drive requires admin privileges for writing.

You may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article helpful.

Comment: the code actually runs. The reason why it didn't save was because i was using the C: drive so i saved the files to a network drive so it works! Thank you!!!